# Docker Image and Java HTTP Post Request

Tags: java, docker

I have a task to ping and endpoint using a post request. The issue I am having is the full endpoint is not clearly defined. I have a docker image and container but I am not sure how to use it in order to make a successful api call.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("/auth");

//Auth object just has 1 field called account
Auth a = new Auth("Test-acc");
Gson gson= new Gson();
String json =  gson.toJson(a);
System.out.println("Json: " + json);

    
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
httpPost.setHeader("Api-Key", "API Key is given for Test-acc"); 

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost); //error as unknown endpoint?
client.close();
//read response
HttpEntity res =  response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(res);
```

The error I get is: client.ClientProtocolException. The endpoint /auth gives me back a session token but I am unsure how to call the full endpoint (e.g. https://.../auth). I assume it has something to do with the docker container that is provided.

To test that the container is running I run docker run and get the response {"message": "ok"}. But other than that, I am unsure how to use it. Will the image in the container help with this?

Docker run command:

```
docker run -p 7902:7902 tesingCompany/testprovider
```

Comment: Is your question "what host should I put to target my docker container ?"

Comment: Yes. I received this task and in the documentation they only reference endpoints such as /auth. But they also provide a docker container. So yes I would like to know what host to point to as the endpoints should be located there. Any ideas?

Comment: Ive updated the question to include docker run command that returns {"message": "ok"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices :

1. You lanch this code from another container on the same user defined docker network, in this case the host is the container name
2. You launch this code from your host and you need to link a port from your host to a port on your container. You do that when you launch your container with the `-p 7092:7092` option. It means your host 7092 port is linked to your container 7092, and you can contact it with `localhost:7092`